# where do i have to find DatabaseEvent Class from? (Flutter) (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

```dart
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class BookableData{
  static FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  Future<List> getBookables() async {
    DatabaseReference ref = database.reference().child('bookables');
    DatabaseEvent event = await ref.once();

    print(event.snapshot.value);
    return [
      Bookable("tirta sari", 15000),
      Bookable("Jaya Badminton", 20000)
    ];

  }
}
```

this is what the error said:

[image]

I've already followed all the instruction on https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/usage

any idea of what i did wrong here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely not using the latest version of [firebase_database](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database/).

[DatabaseEvent](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseEvent-class.html) was added in the version 9.0.0

**Solution:**

[Upgrade](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database/install) your `firebase_database` version to the latest.

Comment: omg thank you so much, its working now